# Swap between UISplitViewController allowed?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, swap

I have a need for two `UISplitViewController` in my app and i am switching back and forth between them using `rootViewController` swap. Are there any risks in getting the app approved ?

thanks

Comment: It's absolutely fine that you use 2 `UISplitViewController`. You don't need care about it.

Comment: @Visput thanks for the ack.

Comment: Added some proofs in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rules that are used during app review are described in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).
Point [10. User interface](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface) has such rules:

> 10.1 Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines.
>   10.3 Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines may be rejected.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW51) have such rules for Split View Controllers:

> 1. Avoid creating a secondary pane that is narrower than the primary pane.
> 2. Avoid displaying a navigation bar in both panes at the same time.
> 3. In general, indicate the current selection in the primary pane in a persistent way.
> 4. Give people alternative ways to access the primary pane, if appropriate.

As you see it says nothing about switching between different objects of `UISplitViewController`. You will be good as you are not trying to display both split controllers at the same time.